# MySql Daemon Failed to Start on CentOS

Tags: mysql

my MySql crashed and here's the log

key_buffer_size=8384512
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 338336 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x29) [0x850989]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x483) [0x6a3ef3]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf710) [0x7fabaf6f6710]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
180516 10:36:25 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
180516 10:36:54 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
180516 10:36:54  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
180516 10:36:54  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log180516 10:36:54 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended

I've try inndodb_force_recovery but still cannot start
can anyone please advise how can i restore my mysql daemon service ?

Comment: I solved it by remove mysql-server then reboot then install again

Comment: Congratulations.  Please check my profile for contact information for future assistance.  Thanks